# Файловые хранилища

Tags: electron, storage

Всем доброго времени суток!
Нужен сервис, который скачивает файл по абсолютному пути. Т.е. на данный момент, используя сервис Mediafire, я закинул туда папку Test, в которой есть подпапка Test2 и в ней лежит файл 123.txt (Test/Test2/123.txt).
Ссылка на скачивание данного файла формируется таким образом:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/hgre03fjdj546/123.txt/file

Мне надо, чтобы формировался путь таким образом:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/Test/Test2/123.txt/file

Google Drive или Dropbox так же пробовал, но у них тоже ссылки, которые не подходят.

Если кто знает, подскажите пожалуйста сервис, который так может делать, либо другие идеи, как это можно реализовать.

P.S Делаю приложение, которое проверяет целостность файлов (ElectronJS).

Comment: github? raw.githubusercontent.com/user/project/branch/file.txt

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но, к сожалению, не подходит. Папка с файлами весит 5 гигов.

Comment: Я не знаю точно, какой там лимит у гитхаба, знаю что у битбакета начиная с 1гб они предупреждают и с 2гб запрещают добавлять файлы. Но это ограничение распространяется только на один репозиторий, при том что вы можете создать сколько угодно отдельных репозиториев и никто вас за это не накажет.

Comment: Важно сохранить иерархию файлов и подпапок в главной папке. Думаю все-таки отойти от использования файловых хранилищ. Может есть еще какие-нибудь идеи, как реализовать это по другому? Поднять сервер для хранения файлов или что-то в этом роде.